# нажатие enter в edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Пытаюсь обработать нажатие enter при вводе текста в edittext:

```
text = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.repeat3text);


            text.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (event != null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                        // обработка нажатия Enter

                        answer = text.getText().toString();

                        dialogans();

                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Также пробовал:

```
      text = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.repeat3text);
        text.setOnKeyListener(enter);
...

private View.OnKeyListener enter = new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            {
                // сохраняем текст, введенный до нажатия Enter в переменную
                answer = text.getText().toString();

                dialogans();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Но все равно при нажатии на телефоне клавиши осуществляется перевод на вторую строчку.

XML:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/repeat3text"
        android:hint="Введите слово"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:lines="1"/>
```

Comment: в дебаге просто посмотрите значение `keyCode ` при нажатии Enter

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам нужно дополнительно настроить *EditText*:

добавьте в приведённую разметку атрибут [`android:imeOptions`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions):

```
   android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте возвращать false из обработчика нажатия.

Answer (score 0):

Испытай иф с отрицанием, у меня работает.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener( new OnEditorActionListener() {
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if( event != null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
        // обработка нажатия Enter
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}};
```

Comment: Чем ваш код отличается от первого варианта кода в вопросе? Если эти отличия есть, опишите их явно и объясните, в чем автор вопроса ошибался.